# How to change passwords for existing FileZilla sites?

Tags: passwords, filezilla

This seems like such a simple question that I can't believe I'm asking this, but I've spent 45 minutes trying to figure this out and just hit dead ends.

It *used* to be that there was a "Password" field in FileZilla Site Manager:

[image]

Now, for some versions of FileZilla it seems, sites look like this:

[image]

The *Password* field is completely gone, and there's nothing related on any of the other tabs.

How can one change the password for an existing site without recreating the entire site from scratch? A password change occured this morning, and now I'm locked out of everything without spending an hour manually recreating everything. I used to be able to just replace the password - how is this done now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an outdated version of FileZilla. The current version’s change log reads as follows:

> 3.54.1 (2021-05-13)
>
> - Fix control visibility logic in Site Manager

Looks like what you are seeing is a bug and that bug was fixed.

In the meantime, you could try switching around the “Logon Type” value.

Comment: I had 3.54.0 and haven't gotten the usual pesky new version notification, but I'll take a look. I changed the Logon Type and that has no effect.

Comment: 3.54.1 indeed fixed, I thought this whole time I was starting to lose my marbles, not that this was a bug...